# Asking for feedback on proofs to already answered questions.

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Often I find myself in two situations, in both cases I have already the solution or proof to a given problem, but:

1. My answer is very is long and hard to follow. I want to improve it but I am not sure hot to simplify the steps.
2. I am not sure if my proof is logically sound/or correct.

In both situations what is the proper etiquette and question format?

Comment: You can use the tag [tag:proof-verification]. I guess the best way to learn about the etiquette and format is to check out a few highly voted threads carrying that tag.